# URLComponents finding nil

Tags: null, ios11, swift4, nsurlcomponents

So my condition here is that if the URL is contained `com://******/sendto/webview` then it should open in a browser inside my app or else it will open in Safari. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
        if let url = homeObject["deeplink_url"] as? String, url != "" {

            if url.contains("com://******/sendto/webview") {

                if url.contains("?url") {

                    self.fixMalformedURL(url)

                } else {

                    if let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: URL(string: url)!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) {
                        let webViewTitle = urlComponents.queryItems!.filter({ $0.name == "title" }).first
                        let webViewURL = urlComponents.queryItems!.filter({$0.name == "url"}).first

                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeaturedWebViewController") as! FeaturedWebViewController
                        vc.webViewTitle = webViewTitle!.value
                        vc.dynamicURL = webViewURL!.value
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                }

            } else {

                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
            }

        }
```

Comment: whats is exactly problem,it  is open in safari every time?

Comment: It is giving me nil value and my app is crashing because of that. It is cashing when it comes to urlComponents. @kirti mali

Comment: @AbhijitHadkar What's giving you a nil value? Please edit your question to focus on the answer to kirti's question, as that's the heart of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may be  crash because  you try to get filter of "title" field but it filed does not exist in url so
here is working code  if url has whitespace then remove it

```
let homeObject = ["deeplink_url":"com://www.xxxyyy.com?title=topPersons&url=google.com"]
    if let url = homeObject["deeplink_url"], url != "" {

      if url.contains("www.xxxyyy.com") {

        if url.contains("?url") {
         //asdj asd asd asdasdfasdf asdfa sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf a sdf asd asdghgjkkjkjkljkljkjkl jkljkljkl jklj jl jljasd asd asdf asd asdf asdf asdf asd asdf asdf aasasaasdasdfasdf asdf asdasdfasdf hoasdasd


        } else {




          if let urlComponents = URLComponents(url:URL.init(string: url)!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
          {


            let webViewTitle = urlComponents.queryItems!.filter({ $0.name == "title" }).first
            let webViewURL = urlComponents.queryItems!.filter({$0.name == "url"}).first

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeaturedWebViewController") as! FeaturedWebViewController
            vc.webViewTitle = webViewTitle!.value
            vc.dynamicURL = webViewURL!.value
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
          }
        }

      } else {

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
      }
```

Comment: Example link :- com://www.xxxyyy.com?title=topPersons&url=http://google.com i have title inside my url still its crashing @kirti mali

Comment: check updated code ,if  url contain white space then remove it

Comment: i dont have any white spacing in my url.    Is it breaking because the URLComponents() method wants proper URL like www.google.com??

Comment: no ,run above it working fine,tested in xcode 9 and swift4

Comment: I fixed by adding percentEncoding to url       "if let urlComponents = URLComponents.init(url: URL.init(string: url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)" thanks for the help @kirti mali